# AJAX url - open up relative path on testing server

Tags: jquery, ajax, localhost

I want to set the url of an ajax request to point to

> http://local.website/page/childpage or local.website/page/childpage

where local is localhost. (I modified host files to change localhost to local)

```
$landingUrl = /page/childpage;

 $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data: data
           url: (landingUrl),
           success: function () {
              console.log("post data sent");
           },
           error: function () {
              $window.open(landingUrl, "_self");
           }
          });
```

The issue is that this current implementation doesn't jump to that URL on success where I want to without a form

Answer (score 0):

Working Code:

```
var landingUrl = "/page/childpage"; // forgot ""
var data = "your data"; // 'data' was not definied

$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data: data, // forgot ,
           url: (landingUrl),
           success: function () {
              console.log("post data sent");
           },
           error: function () {
              window.open(landingUrl, "_self");
           }
});
```